# How to enter variable number of values in variable no of columns defined by user in python using sqlite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, machine-learning, voice-recognition

I am doing an ML project of creating a database using voice input.
I am taking the no of columns the user wants and the column names by voice input.
I am storing the column names in a list.

Now how can I create a table with User entered name, user entered no of columns and column names?

colList=[]

def enterData():

```
print('How many columns do you want in your Database?')
n=int(SpeechToText())
print(n,' Columns?')
ch1=SpeechToText()
print(ch1)
if ch1=='yes' or ch1=='YES':
    for i in range(n):
        print('Enter column',i+1)
        col=SpeechToText()
        colName=col.capitalize()
elif ch1=='no' or ch1=='NO':
    enterData()
```

Answer (score 1):

Human Learning must come before Machine Learning! :)

1. Familiarize yourself with the [python sqlite3 API](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html) and keep the [sqlite3 doc](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) handy.
2. import the sqlite3 library
3. create a database connection
4. create a query string by iterating through `colList=[]`. (Assume it's your intention to keep a list of the columns entered even though the code to do so is not there)
5. execute the query string

You'll probably want to ask the user what to name the table also. NB: columns aren't "in a database", they are "in tables in a database".

**To explain #4 in more detail**:

Remember, the *sql* argument of the *execute* method is simply a string. And since the column list in a sqlite CREATE statement looks a lot like a python tuple, you can do it without an iterator. Something like:

`query_string = "CREATE TABLE tname " + str(tuple(colList))"` will create a string that can be passed to the `execute` method to create the table.

Comment: I actually did import sqlite3 and created the database connection but while creating the table you have to provide the columns and the name for the columns but in my case, it's provided by the user. Is there any way of dynamically doing so?

Comment: additional explanation added to the answer